# Simple onclick menu show next tab

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have menu on left hand side and what I want is when a person clicks on it, the active button movies into next button. So this is my menu using bootstrap:

```
            <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#Test1" data-target="Test1"class="list-group-item active">Score</a>
            <a href="#Test2" data-target="Test2" class="list-group-item">Policy</a>

        </div>
```

This is where I would like to display my text, but the text will come from the database:

```
            <div id="score" class="someText tab-pane active"></div>
            <div id="policy" class="someText tab-pane active"></div>
```

This is the function that gets data;

```
function MethodName() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")",
            data: JSON.stringify(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                      for (var d in data) {
                    $('#score').html(data[d].score);
                }                
             }
        });
    }
```

How would I make it so that when a user click on Score button jquery function with id `$('#Test1').html(data.score);` will show up and when I click Policy button  `$('#Test2').html(data.policy);` data should come up. onclick Policy button the active button should also move from Score button to policy button. I know its confusing but it would be nice to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this:

Put your function in a global scope:

```
function MethodName(elem) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")",
        data: JSON.stringify(),
        context:elem, // put the context here
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
           if($(elem).prop('href') === "#Test1"){ // if #Test1 then place data.score
               $(elem).html(data.score);
           } else if($(elem).prop('href') === "#Test2"){ // if "#Test2" place data.policy
               $(elem).html(data.policy);
           }
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
$(function(){
   $('.list-group a').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.active').removeClass('active'); // removes the active class
      $(this).addClass('active'); // adds the active class to clicked elem
      MethodName(this); // pass the context in method
   });
});
```

---

#### [A small demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/4TXGQ/)

Comment: this changes my text name so when i click Score it changes the name to Policy.  I want that active menu to move into the button i clicked

Comment: Does this mean to put the active class to the clicked elem.

Comment: @User911 take a look at the updated answer and the fiddle added.

Comment: tanks for the demo now it works but my screen flashes each time I click a button. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: have you used the click event i posted. you should use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the flash or jump happens when we click on any link.

Comment: I do have onclick e.preventDefault(); but still it refreshes the page if I remove MethodName(this); it goes back to normal. Another thing in my success handler I am using for loop to display data so how would I turn your if loop into for loop as you did. I've updated my question code. Plus how come your not placing the retrieved data into one of these field `<div id="Test1" class="someText tab-pane active"></div>` - This is where I want to display my database text if button one is clicked.